# No drivers listed?/How to install all drivers? 12.10

Tags: installation, drivers

So i go to system settings in Ubuntu 12.10 and i want to install my drivers but under the Additional Drivers, My LAN doesnt work, Doesnt even pick up that im plugged in threw Ethernet cord. I have a GTX 670M with 3Gb GDDR5 for a video card and would like to use that. Just need help, pretty new to Ubuntu.

Ok when i looked at that other question i did the `sudo lspce -nn` and this is what i got

```
madmike@Mike-GT70:~$ sudo lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1e18] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e57] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1213] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. Device [1969:e091] (rev 13)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
04:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)
```

Let me know if you need any more info? sorry it took so long.

Comment: The driver tool won't work if it can't connect to the internet, so we should fix that first, do you have a wireless network available? That wireless care should work out of the box, then after you connect to it, run the driver tool. Please update your question with the results after you've tried that.

Answer (score 0):

The forums would probably be a better place to discuss this type of problem. Your lspci results show that everything if recognised (with linux most of the drivers are included in the install). You can add both the Nvidia driver and probably the network driver by launching 'Additional Drivers' in settings.

Re-reading your post I notice your ethernet is not working. Best to look for a solution to this first as installing/updating will be problematic without this working. I suggest searching the web and or ubuntu forums [Ubuntu Networking Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=336) for information about your nic. From the lspci your nic is `02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. Device [1969:e091] (rev 13)` [Try here Solved in this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2003542)

Comment: But there is nothing listed under Additional Drivers.... That is my problem. I have no idea what to do about that. I open Additional Drivers in settings and there is nothing there.

Comment: @madmike59 - You have to fix your network issue, first. Additional Drivers will never show anything if it can't connect to the Internet to *find* the additional drivers (or to even know that there *are* any additional drivers to be had).